# Check if an id is contained in a list in SQL and PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a list of products with a separate smaller list where it only selects the ones I chose.

```
  public function SelectCouponGroupList($db, $groupid) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare(
      " SELECT pol.groupid, pol.productid, p.title, p.packageid, po.groupname
        FROM `product_onetime_list` pol
        LEFT JOIN `product` p ON pol.productid = p.productid
        LEFT JOIN `product_onetime` po ON pol.groupid = po.groupid
        WHERE pol.groupid = $groupid
      "
    );

    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $rows;
  }
```

[image: 1]

Now I have a separate file where it outputs every single product, regardless if it is in the group list or not, the image below is an image of the output.

[image: 2]

The code below is a "for each" that outputs all products.

I added an "if" where I'm looking for the correct code where "if it is in the group list" then output "Coupon Added" instead of "Add Coupon"

```
                <?php foreach($lstProduct as $rowProduct) { ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-1">

                      <?php if ("if it is in the group list") {
                        echo 'Coupon Added';
                     } else { 
                        echo 'Add Coupon';
                     } ?>
                    </td>
```

Comment: What is group list also donot post images of code.

Comment: "if it is in the group list" is just a placeholder

Comment: I mean what is in group list , in which variable data of group list is stored.

Comment: added more explanation to clarify.

Comment: Why aren't you using placeholders in that prepared statement? You could be open to SQL injection that way

Comment: I'm trying to get the functionality to work first, then ill do the placeholders

Comment: So what is the code behind `clinics_buttons.vc.php` - `add-coupongroup`?

Comment: I do not think that matters because my question is with the if condition, I updated my question and removed that to avoid confusion.

Comment: It does as we don't know how you are storing/keeping track of the items you've added to the list. Are you storing them in a session, in a seperate table, in a cookie, ...?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($lstProduct as $rowProduct) { ?>
   <tr>
      <td class="col-md-1">
         <?php if ("if it is in the group list") {
              echo 'Coupon Added';
           } else { 
              echo 'Add Coupon';
           } 
endforeach;
?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($lstProduct as $rowProduct) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-md-1">

      <?php if ("if it is in the group list") {
        echo 'Coupon Added';
     } else { 
        echo 'Add Coupon';
     } 
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: An explanation of your code would make you answer far more valuable to everyone.

Comment: You cannot mix bracket `{` and alternate `endforeach;` syntax in the same `foreach` control block.